# How to get the button text through calling a method

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on this demo. Why am I not getting the text of the `#add-point` button?

```js
$("#add-point").on("click", function(){
  activatePointTool();
});

function activatePointTool() {
  var tool = $(this).text().toUpperCase().replace(/ /g, "_");
  console.log(tool);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="add-point" class="btn btn-default btn-tool">Point</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have any "this" in your function. You either need to pass it to your function or execute your code in the on click function.
The this is a really important feature to master when coding in JS.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

```js
$("#add-point").on("click", function(){
  activatePointTool(this);
});

function activatePointTool(el) {
  var tool = $(el).text().toUpperCase().replace(/ /g, "_");
  console.log(tool);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="add-point" class="btn btn-default btn-tool">Point</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to pass the target element to the function, because otherwise `this` will refer to the window object:

```
$("#add-point").on("click", function(){
  activatePointTool(this);
});

function activatePointTool(el) {
  var tool = $(el).text().toUpperCase().replace(/ /g, "_");
  console.log(tool);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the only thing that the function does is to process the action - then forget the named function and simply include the desired action inside the click handler -  in which the 'this' refers to the button that was clicked and you don't need to pass the element to another function.

```js
$("#add-point").on("click", function(){
   var tool = $(this).text().toUpperCase().replace(/ /g, "_");
  console.log(tool);
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="add-point" class="btn btn-default btn-tool">Point</button>
```

Comment: Just wanted to comment the same. Separated named function seems redundant. :)

Comment: thanks @sinisake - i guess the only reason for a named function is if more than one element needs the same function.

Answer (score 0):

> why I am not getting the text of the #add-point button?

`activatePointTool();` means just a separate function call.
The issue is that the target element(`$("#add-point")`) wasn't *bound* with the event handler(`activatePointTool`).
Use the following approach:

```js
$("#add-point").on("click", activatePointTool);

function activatePointTool() {
  var tool = $(this).text().toUpperCase().replace(/ /g, "_");
  console.log(tool);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="add-point" class="btn btn-default btn-tool">Point</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have the context of this is "window". So what you need to do is either change how you call the method

```js
$("#add-point").on("click", function(){
  activatePointTool.call(this);
});

function activatePointTool() {
  var tool = $(this).text().toUpperCase().replace(/ /g, "_");
  console.log(tool);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="add-point" class="btn btn-default btn-tool">Point</button>
```

or just call the method without the closure

```js
$("#add-point").on("click", activatePointTool);

function activatePointTool() {
  var tool = $(this).text().toUpperCase().replace(/ /g, "_");
  console.log(tool);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="add-point" class="btn btn-default btn-tool">Point</button>
```